# TypeError: req.body.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I want to calculate the total sum of nutrients for selected food items in my table. The user can enter the quantity of each food item and select which food items they want to add using the checkboxes. The quantity is multiplied by the nutrients for the food item before getting added. I added a counter for the quantity and then tried to iterate over the req.boy to get the value for each `qty` selected but I get the TypeError.

```
app.post("/calculate", function (req, res) {
  let sqlquery =
    "SELECT SUM(?*calories) AS calories, SUM(?*carbs) AS carbs, SUM(?*fat) AS fat, SUM(?*protein) As protein, SUM(?*salt) As salt, SUM(?*sugar) As sugar FROM food_item WHERE name IN (?)";
  req.body.forEach(function (item) {
    let sum = [
      item.qty,
      item.qty,
      item.qty,
      item.qty,
      item.qty,
      req.param("checkbox"),
    ];
  });
  db.query(sqlquery, sum, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.error(err.message);
    } else {
      res.send(
        "The nutritional information and calorie count of " +
          req.param("checkbox") +
          " is: " +
          JSON.stringify(result)
      );
    }
  });
});
```

```
<% availableFood.forEach(function(food_item, count){ %>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="<%= food_item.name %>" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="qty <%= count %>" value="1" style="width: 30px" />
  </td>
  <td><%= food_item.name %></td>
  <td><%= food_item.typical_values %></td>
  <td><%= food_item.unit_of_the_typical_value %></td>
  <td><%= food_item.calories %></td>
  <td><%= food_item.carbs %></td>
  <td><%= food_item.fat %></td>
  <td><%= food_item.protein %></td>
  <td><%= food_item.salt %></td>
  <td><%= food_item.sugar %></td>
</tr>
<% }) %>
```

Comment: And the contents of req.body are?

Answer (score 0):

req.body is not an array. It is an object. forEach is only available for arrays.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get something from your server use the GET method, not POST.

```
req.body.forEach is not a function
```

An error like this can happen when you are trying to use forEach on undefined data. In your script I can't see that you are sending a request, then you are trying to use forEach on

```
req.body.forEach(function (item) {
```

but if there's no request, so there's no data back. I think that can be a reason.

Try to console log your request body and items which you are passing to functions to see if there's data.
You can try to debug it using the newly created array above your function to see if your function works properly. If it will work then something is wrong with your request as I said above.

Apart from that as @ThirdHouseCaptain told above if your request is okay but you haven't pasted it to question check if your data is the object because you can forEach on arrays, not on object.s

Comment: How do I get the values of `qty <%= count %>`? I want to get the qty values only for the items that have their checkbox selected and someone told me to do it this way.